# Is changing to canonical urls a bad idea if you have an established website with thousands of backlinks?

Tags: url, seo, duplicate, canonical

I have a magento website with thousands of backlinks. I just realized that the categorical structure is negatively affecting my seo. Will switching to canonical break many backlinks? Is it a bad idea? Any suggestions to deal with the duplicate issue without breaking backlinks forever?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No, Unless you are not changing url it wont break

The canonical tag is a relatively quick solution to resolve duplicate content. If your website generates and displays the same (or very similar) content on multiple URLs, the canonical tag could be used to bucket them together and assign one master (canonical) version.

Please refer this [link](https://moz.com/blog/complete-guide-to-rel-canonical-how-to-and-why-not) for more info

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: Mark it as correct if it help - Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to use the up arrow for some reason. It says I have to have more than 15 credits.

Comment: No issue at all - Happy to help you